# C# WPF Problem with building Shapes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, shapes

i have created a shape which lies in canvas Element:

```
<Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="47" Height="71">
  <Polygon Points="25 0 10 43 40 43" Stroke="Black" Fill="Orange" Height="45"   Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Bottom="0" Width="47"></Polygon>
            <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Canvas.Bottom="45" Canvas.Left="15"></Ellipse>
     </Canvas>
```

And i when i click on Button it should create such an element in another Canvas Container!

How could i reuse this constructed Shape several time in my Code without to write it more than one time in XAML?

I have read something about Templates and Styles. But i could not really adept it to my problem.Because i want to create this shapes at runtime.

Comment: Does the shape always exist of a Polygon and Ellipse, only with different values?

Comment: The Always exists and have always the same values! I only want to insert them in my existing canvas at runtime.(several times!!)

Answer (score 0):

you can declare the Polygon in resources like this

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Polygon x:Key = "Poly" Points="25 0 10 43 40 43" Stroke="Black" Fill="Orange" Height="45"   Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Bottom="0" Width="47"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then you can use it like this

```
   <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource Poly}"/>
```

Similarly you can do

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="47" Height="71" x:Key="MyShape">
        <Polygon Points="25 0 10 43 40 43" Stroke="Black" Fill="Orange" Height="45"   Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Bottom="0" Width="47"></Polygon>
        <Ellipse Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" Fill="Black" Canvas.Bottom="45" Canvas.Left="15"></Ellipse>
    </Canvas>
</Window.Resources>

<ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyShape}"/>
```

Comment: How can i add this Control with Resource in the Code-Behind File?

Comment: In code behind you can access this resource via `FindResource("MyShape")`

Comment: I tried this:  Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas();
myCanvas = FindResource("MyShape") as Canvas;
myBaseCanvas.Children.(myCanvas); But i creates one shape and at the second time i get the error: That the element is already under the canvas element!